# How do I conditionally render more than one item in a repeat

Tags: scala, scala.js, udash

I would like to produce a repeating set of nodes using a conditional showIf for one of the nodes something like the following:

```
div<id = "parent">
  div<id = "child1">Child 1</div>
  div<id = "child2">Child 2</div>
  div<>Optional text for child 2</div>
</div>
```

To produce this I might use the repeat function something like the following:

```
div(id := "parent",
  repeat(seqProp)(child =>
   div(id := child.get.id),
   showIf(child.transform(_.otionalText.nonEmpty))(div(child.optionalText.get))
  )
)
```

But no matter what way I seem to try to write this I cannot get the above code to compile. Can someone recommend me a good way do do this?

NOTE. If I have a *Seq[Frag]* then I can call render on that sequence. But *showIf* produces a *Binding* which seems to have an implicit conversion to a *Modifier* but not to a *Frag*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will elaborate a bit on my scenario to explain better the context. I have the following classes:

```
trait MenuItem {
    val id: String
    val label: String
    val subMenu: Option[() => Future[Seq[MenuItem]]]
}

case class MenuNode(item: MenuItem, level: Int, subNodes: Seq[MenuNode])
```

Menu nodes are organised in a tree, with level starting at zero for the root node and incrementing as we go down the tree. I want to be able to dynamically expand/collapse a node by clicking on it. But the DOM will not match up to this hierarchy - it will be flat. So say for example I want to create a 3 level menu of recipes, the DOM would be something like the following:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-1">Vegetables</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-2">Carrot</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item action-item">Soup</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item action-item">Coleslaw</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-2">Potatoes</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-1">Fruits</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-2">Apple</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item action-item">Tart</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item action-item">Cider</button>
    <button class="list-group-item menu-item menu-level-2">Orange</button>
</div>
```

I originally approached this trying to write a recursive function to go through the tree producing the DOM as I recurse. But I've taken a step back and realised a better approach would be to flatten the tree (recursively) to produce all relevant MenuNodes in a sequence. I could then use a SeqProperty to manage how my tree is displayed. Then when a node is expanded/collapsed I only have to update the relevant parts of the SeqProperty accordingly. So I added the following definitions to MenuNode:

```
def flatten(): Seq[MenuNode] = flatten(subNodes.toList, Seq())

private def flatten(nodes: List[MenuNode], slots: Seq[MenuNode]): Seq[MenuNode] = nodes match {
    case h :: t =>
        // Add this node and any sub-slots after it
        flatten(t, (slots :+ h) ++ h.flatten())
    case _ =>
        slots
}

def isSlot(node: MenuNode) = level == node.level && item.id == node.item.id
```

And here is my finalised MenuView:

```
class MenuView(model: ModelProperty[MenuModel]) extends View with Futures {

val seqProp = SeqProperty(model.get.rootNode.flatten())

def getTemplate: Modifier = {
    div(cls := "list-group",
        repeat(seqProp) { slot =>
            button(cls := "list-group-item " + itemStyle(slot.get),
                onclick := { () => handleClick(slot) },
                slot.get.item.label
            ).render
        }
    )
}

model.subProp(_.rootNode).listen { node =>
    // Find the first difference between previous and current
    val prevSlots = seqProp.get
    val curSlots = node.flatten()
    prevSlots.indexWhere(curSlots)(! _.isSlot(_)) match {
        case i if i > 0 =>
            // Replace the slot that was toggled
            seqProp.replace(i - 1, 1, curSlots(i - 1))
            (curSlots.size - prevSlots.size) match {
                case diff if diff > 0 =>
                    // Expand. Insert the new ones
                    seqProp.insert(i, curSlots.drop(i).take(diff): _*)
                case diff =>
                // Collapse. Remove the difference
                seqProp.remove(i, -diff)
            }
        case _ =>
            seqProp.set(curSlots)
    }
}

def itemStyle(node: MenuNode) = "menu-item " +
    (if (node.hasSubMenu) s"menu-level-${node.level}"
        else "action-item") + (if (node.isActive) " item-active" else "")

def handleClick(node: Property[MenuNode]): Unit =
    if (node.get.hasSubMenu) {
        if (! node.get.isExpanded) node.get.expand().success { expanded =>
            model.subProp(_.rootNode).set(model.get.rootNode.replace(expanded))
        }
        else {
            model.subProp(_.rootNode).set(model.get.rootNode.replace(node.get.collapse()))
    }
}
else {
    val vector = node.get.vector
    model.set(model.get.copy(
        rootNode = model.get.rootNode.activate(vector),
        activated = vector
    ))
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one due to the requirement for bindings to render DOM nodes, not `Modifier`s (so they can be replaced accordingly on any change).

First of all, `repeat` tracks only structure changes, so you need to combine 2 bindings. To avoid leaks, you can use `repeatWithNested` in that case.

Secondly, `scalatags.generic.LowPriUtil#OptionFrag` allows you to render `Option` nodes, so you don't need to worry about `showIf` here.

Taking that into account, assuming you have some model class and sequence:

```
case class C(id: String, optionalText: Option[String])
val seqProp = SeqProperty(C("a", Some("")))
```

You could write:

```
div(
  id := "parent",
  repeatWithNested(seqProp)((childProp, nested) => div(
    nested(produce(childProp)(child => Seq(
      div(id := child.id)(child.id).render,
      child.optionalText.render,
    )))
  ).render)
)
```

This unfortunately produces an additional nested `div`, but reacts to both structure and value patches correctly.

You can see this code in action here: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BHG388f/0

If you really wanted to avoid that, you'd have to sacrifice some of these properties e.g. by using `produce` on the `seqProp` and creating the `parent` as its root node inside the builder.